# How to make Bottom Tabs Navigator tab bar not to hide content from View

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a nested Navigator built with a Bottom Tabs Navigator, which also contains a Stack Navigator set as initial route.
The problem is that the main Screen has a View with a **FlatList** inside, among other components.

*When scrolling, the last item (or the content located at most bottom of this view) is always hidden behind the navigator's tabbar, as can be seen in the following screenshot*

[image: item scrolling on main screen with flatlist]

Is there any way to adjust this, without hiding the tabbar?
I'm thinking of creating a constant TABBAR_HEIGHT and assigning this to the main View's style like `style={{marginBottom:TABBAR_HEIGHT}}` but I think this is a dirty way to solve this, right?

PS: I've tried using the following alternatives (without luck)

1. useSafeAreaInsets() hook
2. Using `import {SafeAreaView, SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';` then using SafeAreaProvider wrapping the TabNavigator and using SafeAreaView as main View in MainScreen

Thanks for any tip you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) and have built a custom bottom tab, make sure the bottom tab is NOT absolutely positioned (`position: "absolute"`). Absolutely positioning the bottom tab will free up the space behind it in the container and will let components to render in that space.